# How can my @Rule work together ExpectedException rule?

Tags: junit, rule

I created a @Rule similar to @RunWith parameterized.class so that all testcase can repeat tests with different parameters (I cannot use parameterized.class directly becase my test class already has @Runwith for other purpose).

However, the @Rule does not work when testing the following method:

```
@Test
public void fooTest() {
/*exception is an ExceptedException initialized somewhere else as:
 *@Rule public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
 */
    exception.expect(A);
    exception.expectMessage(B);
    someTestWhichThrowExceptionOfB(); 
}
```

In fact, if I hardcode my parameter as a value, the test passes since it does throw the exception of B.
But if I set my parameter = MyParameterRule.value(), the test does throw an exception of B as well but then fails and saying it fails because exception of B?

I guess in the second case if I use MyParameterRule, then the exception does not work? then why? how to make it work still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can depend on JUnit 4.12, you may be able to use `Parameterized` with `@UseParametersRunnerFactory` (see [the Parameterized Javadoc](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized..html) for details).

As for why your parameterized rule wasn't working, here is a (somewhat long) explanation.

JUnit has an internal assumption that a new instance of your test class is created for each test method. JUnit does this so the state stored in an instance of your test from one test method run doesn't affect the next test method run.

The `ExpectedException` rule has the same expectation. When you call `expect`, it changes the state of the `ExpectedException` field that was created at the initialization time of that field. It modifies it to "expect" an exception to be thrown.

When your Rule tries to run the same method twice (with different parameters) that violates this assumption.  The first time you call a method that calls `expect` it will work, but when you call it again, it might not work, because you are re-using the previously-modified `ExpectedException` rule.

When a JUnit runs a test method for a JUnit4-style test it does the following:

1. Create an instance of the test class.
2. Create a `Statement` that will run the test method
3. If the method's `@Test` annotation uses the `expected` attribute, wrap the `Statement` with another statement that handles expected exceptions
4. If the method's `@Test` annotation uses the `timeout` attribute, wrap the `Statement` with another statement that handles timeouts
5. Wrap that `Statement` with other statements that will call the methods annotated with `@Before` and `@After`
6. Wrap that `Statement` with other statements that will call the rules

For more details, look at [the JUnit source](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java#L279).

So the `Statement` that is passed to your rule wraps an already-constructed class (it has to, so the `apply()` method of your rule is called).

Unfortunately, this means that a `Rule` should not be used to run a test method multiple times, because the test (or it's rules) could have state that was set the previous time the method was run.

If you can't depend on JUnit 4.12, it's possible you can hack this to work by using the `RuleChain` Rule to ensure that the custom Rule you use to run the test multiple times runs "around" the other rules.

Comment: Thanks NamshubWriter. what does " find a way to replace your custom runner with a Rule or a base test class", Note my customer rule is already a rule. it is not a runner.

Comment: BTW, test fails even if I define one parameter in my parameter list so the problem happens even if the test is not repeated

Comment: @user389955 then perhaps just using RuleChain will Help. If not, could you share the code for your custom rule?

Comment: @user389955 I meant that if you can't use `Parameterized` because you need a different custom runner, then you can replace *that* custom runner with a Rule. But if you use JUnit 4.12, there's a better option. I updated my answer.

Comment: NamshubWrite. got. Thanks. 1) that means Rule is not as powerful as I was learned. it does not support multiple Rule in many cases. at least it does not work with Rule ExpectedException. 2) I cannot want to append my new logic to the existing RunWith. 3) I will try RuleChain.

Comment: @user389955 you can use multiple rules in a class, but a rule isn't the best use for running a test multiple times. Did you try `@UseParametersRunnerFactory`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 then you can replace the `ExpectedException` rule with the [Fishbowl](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fishbowl) library.

```java
@Test
public void fooTest() {
  Throwable exception = exceptionThrownBy(
    () -> someTestWhichThrowExceptionOfB());
  assertEquals(A.class, exception.getClass());
  assertEquals("B", exception.getMessage());
}
```

This can be achieved with anonymous classes in Java 6 and 7, too.

```java
@Test
public void fooTest() {
  Throwable exception = exceptionThrownBy(new Statement() {
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
      someTestWhichThrowExceptionOfB();
    }
  });
  assertEquals(A.class, exception.getClass());
  assertEquals("B", exception.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I am not using java 8. :-( Thanks for your response